# Why am I rendering no discernible UI elements in this ReactJS two-way binding with forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Based on https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html , I am trying to make a multi-checkbox-status todo that displays, at start, a textarea. I am trying to follow the model, and where it has:

```
var WithLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('message')} />;
  }
});
```

I have:

```
var Todo = React.createClass(
    {
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function()
        {
        var that = this;
        return {
            children: [],
            description: '',
            id: 0
            };
        },
```

and, in the same class:

```
    render: function()
        {
        var that = this;
        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {that.state.children}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <td>
                        <textarea className="description"
                        placeholder=" Your next task..."
                        onChange={that.onChange} name="description"
                        valueLink={that.linkState('description')}
                        id="description"></textarea><br />
                        <button onClick={that.handleClick}
                        id="save-todo">Save</button>
                    </td>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            );
        }
```

When it renders, there's nothing but an h1 and a jQuery bgstretcher on the page. Chrome's Inspect Element doesn't turn up what I expected and had earlier, a TEXTAREA and a BUTTON inside a table. The log doesn't display any either errors or messages.

At some point I expect further work so that a description is handed off to a new child and re-initialized, but I'm not there yet.

Suggestions for what I should do for it to display?

Comment: Make sure you're including react/addons and that you have a <tr> in your <tfoot>. With those in place does it still not work?

Comment: Thank you. I'm (now) including react-with-addons.min.js and a tr. Same behavior.

Comment: I have two JSXes with two syntactic sugars from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html that display the same lack of behavior: http://pastebin.com/HWAxfb9n and http://pastebin.com/MNQ04uLD . (Any comments about how to get either one working?)